# Minimum Value of graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was doing a test and I got this question wrong and I don't know why...

What is the minimum value of the function $y=\sqrt{49-x^2}$ on the interval $[−5,2]?$

This is the graph according to wolframalpha

[image]

So I swear the value should be $y=7$ and even if you differentiate it and solve it for 0 you get 7.... what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 3):

$y = 7 = \sqrt{49 - 0^2}$ happens to be the *maximal* value of $y$, which occurs when $x=0$. But that's a *maximum* and not a minimum. Recall that when we set the derivative equal to zero, we solve for $x$ to find critical points, but those critical points may be where $y$ is a local maximum, or a local minimum, or neither. In this case, at $x = 0$, the function attains a ***maximum*** value of $7$.

Now, we need $x\in [-5, 2]$. The least value of $y$ occurs when $x = -5$. Then $y =\sqrt{49 -(-5)^2} = \sqrt{49- 25} = \sqrt{24}$. Any other value of $y$, for $x \in [-5, 2]$ is greater than $y =\sqrt{24}$.

Note that if $x$ would not be restricted to the given interval, then when $x = 7$ or $x=-7$, we have that $y = 0$, and since $y$ can never be negative, $y = 0$ would be minimal. But the question specifies the minimal value of $y$ *on the given interval*, which does **not** contain $x = -7$, nor does it contain $x = 7$. So  $y \neq 0$ *anywhere on the given interval.*

Answer (score 0):

When you set the derivative equal to $0$, you solve for $x$.  For this problem you get the local maximum point $x=0$, which corresponds to the local max value $y=7$.

Answer (score 0):

When you take the derivative of a function in order to look for critical points, the point you find may not always be a minimum, sometimes it can be a maximum.  Taking the first derivative will not tell you which of the two it is, only that there is a min or max there.  In your case, you found the max.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29